# How to get Id of selected value in Mat-Select Option in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material-5

How to get the id of selected option value in mat-select angular 5. Get only value of selected option in onchangeevent. but how can get id of selected option value.

```
 client.component.html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Client*" #clientValue  (change)="changeClient($event)">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let client of clientDetails"   [value]="client.clientName">
      {{client.clientName |  json}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

client.component.ts file
export class Client{
     changeClient(event){
     console.log(event);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For that you need to :

Change `(change)="changeClient($event)"` to `(change)="changeClient($event.value)"`

and from `[value]="client.clientName"` to `[value]="client.id"`

```xml
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Client*" #clientValue  (change)="changeClient($event.value)">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let client of clientDetails"   [value]="client.id">
      {{client.clientName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data)**

Comment: But I need the value and id both in changeclient event. For that [value]="client.id+,+client.value"  and changeClient($event.value) ...this is the way can I get both value or any other way to get it

Comment: Understood but how to get selected index from mat-select?

Comment: @KT , in working demo `changeClient2` is getting index of selected item , please check

Comment: @VivekDoshi..............  can you please help me out with this issue..?

Comment: oh Im so sorry .. missed to add the link......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188340/unable-to-implement-put-request-in-angular-2-getting-an-error-null-values-are.. please have a look

Comment: @VivekDoshi... can you please suggest me any solution...?

Answer (score 56):

The question is specific to Angular 5 but for others coming here with a newer version of Angular, the `(change)` event won't work for mat-select.

In **Angular 6** the `(change)` event has been changed to `(selectionChange)`.

So it would be:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Client*" #clientValue  (selectionChange)="changeClient($event.value)">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let client of clientDetails" [value]="client.id">
      {{client.clientName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in the component:

```
changeClient(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50223943/3291390) and [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api).

Comment: In angular 8, its working with (selectionChange). Thank you

Comment: Thank you, this works wonders in Angular 14

Answer (score 2):

You can also subscribe to the values change of the `mat-select`
by using the `ViewChild` decorator and `ngAfterViewInit` which is less 'html-intrusive'.

Here is an example :

[HTML]

```xml
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="auto">
    <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select #matSelect required> //the #matSelect is important here
            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.value">
                {{type.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[TS]

```
 import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material';

 @Component({
        selector: 'app-export-security-pack-material',
        templateUrl: './export-security-pack-material.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./export-security-pack-material.component.scss']
 })

 export class ExportSecurityPackMaterialComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor() {}

    types: Object[] = [
        { value: 'example-value-0', viewValue: 'ExampleViewValue0' 
        },
        { value: 'example-value-1', viewValue: 'ExampleViewValue1' }
    ];

    @ViewChild('matSelect') matSelect: MatSelect;
       //Reference Variable //variable Name //Type

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.matSelect.valueChange.subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
 }
```

With this your value should be logged in the development console `Ctrl+Shift+I` or `F12` everytime you change your selector value.

or you can literally just do this if you dont need onchange :

[HTML]

```xml
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="auto">
    <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="matSelectValue" required> <---
            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.value">
                {{type.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Component => app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialDropDown, PAYMENT_MODES } from './order.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  sampleForm: FormGroup;
  paymentModes: MaterialDropDown[];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentModes = PAYMENT_MODES;
    this.sampleForm = new FormGroup({
      payment_mode: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.sampleForm.controls;
  }

  onPaymentSelection() {
    console.log(this.sampleForm.value.payment_mode);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.sampleForm.value);
  }
}
```

> Module => app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    MatFormFieldModule, 
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Model => order.model.ts

```
export interface MaterialDropDown {
    value: string;
    viewValue: string;
}

export const PAYMENT_MODES: MaterialDropDown[] = [
    { value: 'Cash', viewValue: 'Cash' },
    { value: 'cheque', viewValue: 'Cheque' },
    { value: 'dd', viewValue: 'Demand Draft' },
    { value: 'neft', viewValue: 'NEFT' },
    { value: 'rtgs', viewValue: 'RTGS' },
    { value: 'upi', viewValue: 'UPI' }
];
```

> View => app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Payment Mode</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="payment_mode" (ngModelChange)="onPaymentSelection($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let payment_mode of paymentModes" [value]="payment_mode.value">
                {{ payment_mode.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-hint *ngIf="!f.touched">Please select a valid Payment Mode.</mat-hint>
        <div *ngIf="!f.payment_mode.valid && f.payment_mode.touched">
            <mat-error *ngIf="f.payment_mode.errors.required">Payment Mode field is required</mat-error>
        </div>
    </mat-form-field>
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="sampleForm.invalid">Save</button>
</form>
<p style="color: #f00">Check Console for outputs</p>
```

> CSS => app.component.css

```
mat-form-field { width: 280px; margin-right: 35px}
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4sztec)