# Angular 6 Material mat-select change method removed

Tags: angular, angular6

In Angular Material Design 6, the (change) method was removed.
How should I replace the change method to execute code in the component when the user changes selection?

Answer (score 536, accepted):

The changed it from `change` to `selectionChange`.

```
<mat-select (change)="doSomething($event)">
```

is now

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)">
```

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: I hate this so much. Yesterday I thought it was a cool day to upgrade to Angular 6. Once again, they changed the syntax.

Comment: They need a `(changeEventChange)` event to detect when the change event changes.

Comment: (selectionChange) is now updated to (onSelectionChange).

Comment: @Debadatta - Where did you see this at?  I still see `selectionChange` https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: All the comments above only further highlight why it makes sense to stick to a reactive forms appoach, as per my answer below, where possible.  On a side note, I don’t think the comments are very fair because the Angular Material guys do an amazing job and we get it for free.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I used both methods, selectionChange was not working, then I read in another stackOverflow answer, where it was mentioned.

Comment: <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="Zone" (selectionChange)="BasedonZone(Zone)">

Answer (score 32):

If you're using Reactive forms you can listen for changes to the select control like so..

```
this.form.get('mySelectControl').valueChanges.subscribe(value => { ... do stuff ... })
```

Comment: It's worth noting that using the above reactive forms approach you are less tied to the UI and less likely to have problems as that UI framework evolves

Comment: Just to note here that if you need to `.updateValueAndValidity` the control don't forget to pass `{ emitEvent: false }` in order to avoid `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. On the other hand thanks for hint (+1), it lead me to what I needed.

Comment: Should I unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy if I follow the approach?

Comment: You always need to cleanup your subscriptions to avoid memory leaks and unexpected behaviour.

Comment: you can also go with `this.form.controls.yourControlName.valueChanges.subscribe(values => { console.log('new value', value); }`

Comment: @Joseph using your approach how can I get an index of the selected item?

Answer (score 18):

For:

**1) mat-select `(selectionChange)="myFunction()"` works in angular as:**

sample.component.html

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Select your option" [(ngModel)]="option" name="action" 
      (selectionChange)="onChange()">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of actions" [value]="option">
       {{option}}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

sample.component.ts

```
actions=['A','B','C'];
onChange() {
  //Do something
}
```

**2) Simple html select `(change)="myFunction()"` works in angular as:**

sample.component.html

```
<select (change)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="regObj.status">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

sample.component.ts

```
onChange() {
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For me `(selectionChange)` and the suggested `(onSelectionChange)` didn't work and I'm not using `ReactiveForms`. What I ended up doing was using the `(valueChange)` event like:

```
<mat-select (valueChange)="someFunction()">
```

And this worked for me

Comment: I'm using a template form, and worked to me using the following: 

`<mat-select placeholder="Select an option" [(ngModel)]="project.managerId" name="managerId" required
  (selectionChange)="fillComanager(project.managerId)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let manager of managers" [value]="manager.id">
 {{ manager.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>`

Answer (score 5):

I have this issue today with mat-option-group. 
The thing which solved me the problem is using in other provided event of mat-select : 
**valueChange**

I put here a little code for understanding :

```
<mat-form-field >
  <mat-label>Filter By</mat-label>
  <mat-select  panelClass="" #choosedValue (valueChange)="doSomething1(choosedValue.value)"> <!-- (valueChange)="doSomething1(choosedValue.value)" instead of (change) or other event-->

    <mat-option >-- None --</mat-option>
      <mat-optgroup  *ngFor="let group of filterData" [label]="group.viewValue"
                    style = "background-color: #0c5460">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of group.options" [value]="option.value">
          {{option.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Mat Version:

> "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",

Comment: Thx for the answer, i was looking for this to get the value and viewValue from the html-binding. With selectionChange it does only send the value but not the viewValue via $event.

Answer (score 1):

For me `...(click)="myFunction()"...` worked; nothing from above.

Answer (score 1):

<mat-select (change)="doSomething($event)">

is now
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)">

Comment: Works for me as of Angular 16.1.0