# how to create a custom directive for mat select and listen to the change event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, mat-select

In my project it's nessesary to use ElementRef's `nativeelement.value` because of some readonly errors.
only my directive

```
export class DeliveryAcrossDirective {
  @Input('key') key: string;
  @Input('component') component: string;
  constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>
  ) {
    this.key = '';
    this.component = '';
  }
  @HostListener('change') onChange() {
    console.log('noticed something');

    this.store.dispatch<IAction<IAdjust>>({
        type: RDX_DELIVERY_ACROSS_ADJUST,
        payload: {
          key: this.key,
          value: this.elementRef.nativeElement.value
        },
        component: this.component
      })
  }

}
```

doesn't capture the change event from my mat select

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" [@transformRightLeftStateTrigger]="stateDown | async">
  <mat-label>
    {{ country | async }}
  </mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="countryFormControl"
  appDeliveryAcross
  [key]="'iso'"
  [component]="'delivery-across'" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let language of (languages | async)"  [value]="language.value">
      {{ language.country }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

while classic inputs do

```
        <mat-form-field class="full-width" [@transformRightLeftStateTrigger]="stateDown | async">
          <input matInput
          [formControl]="minFormControl"
          [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
          placeholder="Minimaal"
          appDeliveryAcross
          [key]="'min'"
          [component]="'delivery-across'"
          type="number">
        </mat-form-field>
```

does anyone know a way how to capture the change event from a mat select with a directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which version of Angular Material you are using, but probably `change` event simple doesn't exist for the `mat-select` https://stackoverflow.com/a/50223943/9602452

Seems like you have modify your directive for `mat-select`s

Answer (score 1):

You should be listening to the `selectionChange` event

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appMyDirective]',
})
export class MyDirective {
    constructor() {}

    @HostListener('selectionChange', ['$event'])
    onSelectionChange(event: MatSelectChange): void {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect changes of `mat-select` you don't need to `HostListener`, just subscribe `selectionChange` of `MatSelect`

```
export class DeliveryAcrossDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  selectionSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private host: MatSelect
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectionSub = this.host.selectionChange.subscribe(option => {
      console.log(option);
      // Do something
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.selectionSub?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```