# How to call function on change event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to call a function, once the value of dropdown is changed.

I have done this without Angular Material.
Here's my ts and html files.

```js
  selected="pending";
  
  getRequests(event: any) {
    this.selected = event.target.value;
    if(this.selected=="pending")
    console.log("Inside Pending Requests")
    else
    console.log("Inside Granted Requests")
  }
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 70%;" appearance="fill">
  <select (change)="getRequests($event)">
    <option value="pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="granted">Granted</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now, I want to implement this with the help of **Angular Material Select Component.
Calling the getRequests() function is not working as expected**. Somebody please help me on this one. Thanks in advance.

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-left: 70%;" appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Status</mat-label>
<mat-select [(value)]="selected" (change)="getRequests($event)" >
  <mat-option value="pending">Pending</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="granted">Granted</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: When you use any library, check the API, in material e.g. you has [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api). The properties marked as `@Output` are the events you can attach, see that all has some like `EventEmitter<T>`, the `T` is the type of the `$event` you pass to the function. BTW, if only want change a variable use `[(ngModel)]="your variable`, to make a [two-ways-binding](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#displaying-and-updating-properties-with-ngmodel)

Answer (score 3):

The api is `selectionChange` i.e. `(selectionChange)="getRequests($event)"`.

See the docs https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Answer (score 3):

In Angular Material Design 6 and above, the `(change)` method was removed. Instead use `selectionChange`

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)">
```

Read more about here: [Angular 6 Material mat-select change method removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222738/angular-6-material-mat-select-change-method-removed)

Answer (score 3):

Use `selectionChange` intead of change

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-left: 70%;" appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Status</mat-label>
<mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="getRequests($event)" >
  <mat-option value="pending">Pending</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="granted">Granted</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Then you should be able to access value from event object value property

```
 getRequests(event: MatSelectChange) {
    this.selected = event.value;
    if(this.selected=="pending")
    console.log("Inside Pending Requests")
    else
    console.log("Inside Granted Requests")
  }
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pujz7z?file=src/app/select-overview-example.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

your mat-select has an event that is emitted every time selection is changed. It is called selectionChange as per angular documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api
so maybe try to chage your (change) to (selectionChange) like this:

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-left: 70%;" appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Status</mat-label>
<mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="getRequests($event)" >
  <mat-option value="pending">Pending</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="granted">Granted</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```