# Unable to implement PUT request in angular 2 ,getting an error "null values are not allowed"

Tags: angular, swagger-ui, angular-http

I have implemented GET request in my application and able to fetch data for my Account Table in the **AccountComponent**.

When I click on a particular row in the **DataGrid** , I get a **POPUP** window where I can access the row_data and using the dropdowns can update the **DataGrid **

But when I am selecting the required values for the dropdowns and trying to update, I'm getting the following error in my console.

```
Error code is : Error {"message":"Null values are not allowed","error":"java.lang.NullPointerException","path":"/spacestudy/rockefeller/admin/account/saveAttributes"}
```

Please access my sample StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-in-angular?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Below shown are the screenshots of my sample app.

```
This is my Account Table
```

[image]

```
When I click on a row here is my POPUP
```

[image]

```
When I try to update I'm getting the following error in my console & Network tab
```

[image]
[image]

```
But when I'm trying to save it from backend through Swagger UI,then I'm able to successfully update the data
```

[image]

[image]

Can anybody please help me to solve this issue....?

Latest screen shot
[image]

Comment: seems like you aren't sending all the data from the form. can you post screenshot of request payload? it's at the bottom of 'headers' tab

Comment: okay i will update my question with that screen shot

Comment: I have updated my question... please check it out.........!

Comment: i meant request payload from network tab. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqUtq.png

Comment: Dude - too much irrelevant images..... and stackblitz does not work as it calls LAN hosts.

Comment: update your stackblz with JSOn data instead of `http://192.168.16.89:7072/spacestudy/rockefeller/control/searchfilter/loadDepartments`. Because we are not able to access it

Comment: @Heena update your code also as stackbiltz wont access locally or lan hosted services , also console.log your payload which you are sending in your put request and the java pojo object its getting mapped to

Comment: @Heena place a debugger in `updateAccount()` func and check if any value is being passed null or undefined in it and as everyone else said update your stackblitz with json data as we can't access your local host.

Comment: thanks to everyone for your feedback .. I will be back with the modifications ...

Comment: please access my modified stackblitz here ..https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-in-angular-vnnwhr?file=app%2Faccountdetail.service.ts

Comment: @AbdulRafay... can you please check this updated stackblitz...https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-in-angular-vnnwhr?file=app%2Faccountdetail.service.ts

Comment: @RameshRajendran...  can you please check this updated stackblitz..https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-in-angular-vnnwhr?file=app%2Faccountdetail.service.ts

Comment: still I am not able to see the data in grid

Comment: i have added the json data files for all the get requests..I can see the data in grid in stackblitz

Comment: please access this link ...https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-in-angular-vnnwhr?file=app%2Faccountdetail.service.ts